# \ref, make figure/table reference automatically toggle between "above" or "below"

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Is it possible to automatically include a reference to the *position* of a labeled object (Table, Figure) in text? By this I mean the following:

Say I have labeled a figure in chapter 1:

```
\label{fig:one}
```

Then I refer to it in text by using:

```
See Figure~\ref{fig:one}
```

Which produces "See Figure 1.1" as desired. I'd like to be able to have it produce: "See Figure 1.1, above" or "See Figure 1.1, below", automatically detecting whether to produce "above" or "below" depending on whether the figure will be placed above that position on the final page.

Comment: Consider using the **varioref** package, which has facilities just for that purpose.

Answer (score 9):

The **varioref** package is intended just for similar things. Its command `\vref` adds suitable words to the number, depending on the context. For example, in twosided printing, it might resolve a reference `see Figure~\vref{x}` to

> see Figure 1.1 on the facing pages

if this is the case. It's very customizable *and* provides support for different languages than English.

Comment: The `varioref` package is indeed the way to go IMHO, but I made the experience that some people (like Ph.D. supervisors) are not used to such things and tend to dislike it. A simple "see Figure N.M" does it mot of the time.

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for the input. Indeed it's for my dissertation. Appreciate style tips as well.

Comment: I believe, IMHO, it is due to the fact that a dissertation formally is oral and "above" and "below" are not eloquent, having no meanings. Should use "the before mentioned" and "the next."